# Variable as Values in ActionScript 3.0 dynamic animation

Tags: actionscript-3, animation, actionscript, dynamic

I'm using AS3.0 and
I'm trying to make a function that will generate a random value between 1-550 (the default width of a flash stage), will animate a movie clip object to move to that point along the x axis, and then make another movie clip object drop from that very point, now thats as far as I got so far (notice the numbers on the right hand side are just there to number the line!!) ("base" is the instance that moves along the X axis, and "ball" is the instance that drops from that point).

```
function dropBall() {
var randomNum:Number = Math.random() * 550;//The variable "random" equals a random value between 1 to 550
 var xAxis:int = Math.round(randomNum); // the variable "xAxis" equals the value of "random", just rounded.
     var baseTween:Tween = new Tween(base, x, null, 0, xAxis, 1, true);//Thats the problematic line!!! the value "xAxis" is 
 //not valid.
     ball.x = xAxis; //Makes the ball appear at the random point. here the variable "xAxis" works just fine as a value.
     var ballTween:Tween = new Tween(ball, "y", null, 0, 500, 1.2, true); // animates the drop of the ball along the Y axis.
 }
```

Anybody knows why doesn't the "xAxis" variable works as a value for the new Tween() method on line 4???
Thanks for ANY help :D

Comment: Unrelated to you actual question, but to get a range of random numbers between 1 and max, you should be using a `ceil` not a `round`. Rounding would sometimes round down to zero and throw off the distrution at either end if the set.

Comment: What is the syntax for using celi?

Comment: Just change `Math.round()` to `Math.ceil()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var baseTween:Tween = new Tween(base, "x", null, 0, xAxis, 1, true);
```

Tween property should be a string.